# How can I scrape data from the Israeli Bureau of Statistics web query tool?

Tags: python, perl, r, screen-scraping, security

The following url:

http://www.cbs.gov.il/ts/ID40d250e0710c2f/databank/series_func_e_v1.html?level_1=31&level_2=1&level_3=7

Gives a data generator of information from the Israeli government which limits the number of data points extracted to a maximum of 50 series at a time.  I wonder, is it possible (and if so, how) to write a webscraper (in your favorite language/software) that can follow the clicks on each step to be able to get all of the series in a specific topic.

Thanks.

Comment: You've got to pick a language and learn it.  Unless you already know python, perl, and r, how would you take that next step of implementing a solution once someone answers that yes it's possible in a specific language?  Any of the languages you mentioned will handle your task.  Which one do you know sufficiently well to implement your solution?

Comment: I know R well enough to handle this.  But I was not sure if R can handle it, so I wanted to ask of people from other languages if it is possible or if there is some fundamental problem with doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To submit the forms, you can use [Python's mechanize module](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/):

```
import mechanize
import pprint
import lxml.etree as ET
import lxml.html as lh
import urllib
import urllib2

browser=mechanize.Browser()
browser.open("http://www.cbs.gov.il/ts/ID40d250e0710c2f/databank/series_func_e_v1.html?level_1=31&level_2=1&level_3=7")
browser.select_form(nr=0)
```

Here we peek at the options available:

```
pprint.pprint(browser.form.controls[-2].items)
# [<Item name='1' id=None selected='selected' contents='Volume of orders for the domestic market' value='1' label='Volume of orders for the domestic market'>,
#  <Item name='2' id=None contents='Orders for export' value='2' label='Orders for export'>,
#  <Item name='3' id=None contents='The volume of production' value='3' label='The volume of production'>,
#  <Item name='4' id=None contents='The volume of sales' value='4' label='The volume of sales'>,
#  <Item name='5' id=None contents='Stocks of finished goods' value='5' label='Stocks of finished goods'>,
#  <Item name='6' id=None contents='Access to credit for the company' value='6' label='Access to credit for the company'>,
#  <Item name='7' id=None contents='Change in the number of employees' value='7' label='Change in the number of employees'>]

choices=[item.attrs['value'] for item in browser.form.controls[-2].items]
print(choices)
# ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']

browser.form['name_tatser']=['2']
browser.submit()
```

We can repeat this for each of the subsequent forms:

```
browser.select_form(nr=1)

choices=[item.attrs['value'] for item in browser.form.controls[-2].items]
print(choices)
# ['1576', '1581', '1594', '1595', '1596', '1598', '1597', '1593']

browser.form['name_ser']=['1576']
browser.submit()

browser.select_form(nr=2)

choices=[item.attrs['value'] for item in browser.form.controls[-2].items]
print(choices)
# ['32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41']

browser.form['data_kind']=['33']
browser.submit()

browser.select_form(nr=3)
browser.form['ybegin']=['2010']
browser.form['mbegin']=['1']
browser.form['yend']=['2011']
browser.form['mend']=['5']
browser.submit()
```

At this point you have three options:

1. Parse the data from the HTML source
2. Download an .xls file
3. Download an XML file

I don't have any experience parsing .xls in Python, so I passed over this option.

Parsing the HTML is possible with `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml`. Perhaps 
this would have been the shortest solution, but finding the right XPaths for the HTML was not immediately clear to me, so I went for the XML:

To download the XML from the cbs.gov.il website, one clicks on a button that calls a javascript function. Uh oh -- mechanize can not execute javascript functions. Thankfully, the javascript merely assembles a new url. Pulling out the parameters with `lxml` is easy:

```
content=browser.response().read()
doc=lh.fromstring(content)
params=dict((elt.attrib['name'],elt.attrib['value']) for elt in doc.xpath('//input'))
params['king_format']=2
url='http://www.cbs.gov.il/ts/databank/data_ts_format_e.xml'
params=urllib.urlencode(dict((p,params[p]) for p in [
    'king_format',
    'tod',
    'time_unit_list',
    'mend',
    'yend',
    'co_code_list',
    'name_tatser_list',
    'ybegin',
    'mbegin',
    'code_list',
    'co_name_tatser_list',
    'level_1',
    'level_2',
    'level_3']))

browser.open(url+'?'+params)
content=browser.response().read()
```

Now we reach another stumbling block: the XML is encoded in `iso-8859-8-i`.
Python does not recognize this encoding. Not knowing what to do, I simply replaced `iso-8859-8-i` with `iso-8859-8`. I don't know what bad side-effects this might cause.

```
# A hack, since I do not know how to deal with iso-8859-8-i
content=content.replace('iso-8859-8-i','iso-8859-8')
doc=ET.fromstring(content)
```

Once you get this far, parsing the XML is easy:

```
for series in doc.xpath('/series_ts/Data_Set/Series'):
    print(series.attrib)
    # {'calc_kind': 'Weighted',
    #  'name_ser': 'Number Of Companies That Answered',
    #  'get_time': '2011-06-21',
    #  'name_topic': "Business Tendency Survey - Distributions Of Businesses By Industry, Kind Of Questions And Answers  - Manufacturing - Company'S Experience Over The Past Three Months - Orders For Export",
    #  'time_unit': 'Month',
    #  'code_series': '22978',
    #  'data_kind': '5-10 Employed Persons',
    #  'decimals': '0',
    #  'unit_kind': 'Number'}

    for elt in series.xpath('obs'):
        print(elt.attrib)
        # {'time_period': ' 2010-12', 'value': '40'}
        # {'time_period': ' 2011-01', 'value': '38'}
        # {'time_period': ' 2011-02', 'value': '40'}
        # {'time_period': ' 2011-03', 'value': '36'}
        # {'time_period': ' 2011-04', 'value': '30'}
        # {'time_period': ' 2011-05', 'value': '33'}
```

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#SYNOPSIS) and [WWW::HtmlUnit](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-HtmlUnit/lib/WWW/HtmlUnit.pm#SYNOPSIS).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize;

my $m = WWW::Mechanize->new;

#get page
$m->get("http://www.cbs.gov.il/ts/ID40d250e0710c2f/databank/series_func_e_v1.html?level_1=31&level_2=1&level_3=7");

#submit the form on the first page
$m->submit_form(
    with_fields => {
        name_tatser => 2, #Orders for export
    }
);

#now that we have the second page, submit the form on it
$m->submit_form(
    with_fields => {
        name_ser => 1576, #Number of companies that answered
    }
);

#and so on...

#printing the source HTML is a good way
#to find out what you need to do next
print $m->content;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also take a look at [Scrapy](http://www.scrapy.org), which is a web crawler framework for Python. See 'Scrapy at a glance' for an introduction: http://doc.scrapy.org/intro/overview.html